# Install Python in Wine

Tags: wine, python

I need to install the Windows version Python 2.7.5 32Bit on my Ubuntu Box in Wine (because I test Euler Math Toolbox on Wine, and this cannot use the native Python).

Whatever I do, I get the an error at the end of the installation (see screendump). I tried to install "python.2.7.5.msi" and even "winetricks python26". The error is always the same. Seems the installer does not work.

I did that earlier in another Ubuntu system, and it worked.

Thanks for help!

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Here is the output of "winetricks python26"

```
rene@rene-stick:~/Arbeitsfläche$ winetricks python26
Executing w_do_call python26
Executing load_python26
Executing mkdir -p /home/rene/.cache/winetricks/python26
Downloading http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.2/python-2.6.2.msi to /home/rene/.cache/winetricks/python26
--2013-08-08 14:47:10--  http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.2/python-2.6.2.msi
Auflösen des Hostnamen »www.python.org (www.python.org)«... 82.94.164.162, 2001:888:2000:d::a2
Verbindungsaufbau zu www.python.org (www.python.org)|82.94.164.162|:80... verbunden.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, warte auf Antwort... 200 OK
Länge: 14536192 (14M) [application/x-msi]
In »»python-2.6.2.msi«« speichern.

100%[======================================>] 14.536.192   683KB/s   in 21s    

2013-08-08 14:47:32 (673 KB/s) - »»python-2.6.2.msi«« gespeichert [14536192/14536192]

Executing mkdir -p /home/rene/.cache/winetricks/python26
Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pywin32/pywin32/Build%20214/pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe to /home/rene/.cache/winetricks/python26
--2013-08-08 14:47:34--  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pywin32/pywin32/Build%20214/pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe
Auflösen des Hostnamen »downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)«... 216.34.181.59
Verbindungsaufbau zu downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)|216.34.181.59|:80... verbunden.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, warte auf Antwort... 302 Found
Platz: http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pywin32/pywin32/Build%20214/pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe [folge]
--2013-08-08 14:47:34--  http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pywin32/pywin32/Build%20214/pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe
Auflösen des Hostnamen »dfn.dl.sourceforge.net (dfn.dl.sourceforge.net)«... 194.95.248.253, 2001:638:d:c101:acdc:1979:2:1001
Verbindungsaufbau zu dfn.dl.sourceforge.net (dfn.dl.sourceforge.net)|194.95.248.253|:80... verbunden.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, warte auf Antwort... 302 Found
Platz: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pywin32/pywin32/Build%20214/pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe?download&failedmirror=dfn.dl.sourceforge.net [folge]
--2013-08-08 14:47:34--  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pywin32/pywin32/Build%20214/pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe?download&failedmirror=dfn.dl.sourceforge.net
Wiederverwendung der bestehenden Verbindung zu downloads.sourceforge.net:80.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, warte auf Antwort... 302 Found
Platz: http://switch.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pywin32/pywin32/Build%20214/pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe [folge]
--2013-08-08 14:47:35--  http://switch.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pywin32/pywin32/Build%20214/pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe
Auflösen des Hostnamen »switch.dl.sourceforge.net (switch.dl.sourceforge.net)«... 130.59.138.21, 2001:620:0:1b::21
Verbindungsaufbau zu switch.dl.sourceforge.net (switch.dl.sourceforge.net)|130.59.138.21|:80... verbunden.
HTTP-Anforderung gesendet, warte auf Antwort... 200 OK
Länge: 6438204 (6,1M) [application/octet-stream]
In »»pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe«« speichern.

100%[======================================>] 6.438.204    588KB/s   in 10s    

2013-08-08 14:47:45 (612 KB/s) - »»pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe«« gespeichert [6438204/6438204]

Executing wine msiexec /i python-2.6.2.msi ALLUSERS=1
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:sxs:cache_QueryAssemblyInfo 0x3ec228, 0x00000002, L"Microsoft.VC90.CRT,version=\"9.0.21022.8\",publicKeyToken=\"1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\",processorArchitecture=\"x86\",type=\"win32\"", 0x32f8c8
fixme:sxs:cache_QueryAssemblyInfo 0x3ec228, 0x00000002, L"policy.9.0.Microsoft.VC90.CRT,version=\"9.0.21022.8\",publicKeyToken=\"1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\",processorArchitecture=\"x86\",type=\"win32-policy\"", 0x32f8c8
fixme:msi:ControlEvent_SpawnWaitDialog Doing Nothing
err:msi:ACTION_InstallFiles compressed file wasn't installed (L"C:\\Python26\\Lib\\test\\readme.txt")
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"InstallFiles" returned 1603
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"ExecuteAction" returned 1603
------------------------------------------------------
Note: command 'wine msiexec /i python-2.6.2.msi ALLUSERS=1' returned status 67.  Aborting.
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I have tried on another Ubuntu system now. I had this running in a VirtualBox since one or two months (the other is a native system). There, Python can be installed. Seems, it depends on the Wine version.

Answer (score 9):

A friend solved this by installing Wine 1.6, I think.

His commands were:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install wine1.6 winetricks`
4. `winetricks python26`

Maybe the update to Wine 1.6 is the main point. I do not know. After that, you can install Python 27.5. with no problems at all.

Comment: I can confirm that `wine msiexec /i python-3.4.2.msi /L*v log.txt ` commands can install Python 3.4 on wine-1.6.2 where the msi file is from python.org. `wine start python-3.4.2.msi` fails for some reason on my machine YMMV.

Comment: After installing python using winetricks I'm getting `wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\python.exe"` when try to run `wine python`

Comment: @Fabiotk Me too. Have you resolved that issue?

Comment: Ensure you're installing in a wine64 or wine32 context correctly.
To install it properly I had to use `wine64` in my case

Answer (score 2):

If you get

```
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\python.exe"
```

You can run it after install with

```
wine /Users/user/.wine/drive_c/Python26/python.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

actually You can use the latest python3.7 / python2.7 on wine:

basically all You need is to install python on a windows machine (for "current user" , not for "All Users"), and copy the whole directory to the wine machine.

Alternatively You can download it from Python [releases download pages](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/)

Then add following paths in the wine registry : "c:\python37;C:\python37\Scripts;..."  and everything works fine.

I provided [some convenient Scripts](https://github.com/bitranox/install_python_on_wine_and_travis) on Github to do that automatically for Ubuntu.
I would recommend to use those, because they are maintained and updated.
Since Links can change, find the current install script below.

However, You need to decide first if You want to Install WINE STABLE, WINE DEVELOP or WINE STAGING (I suggest WINE DEVELOP).

Then You need to decide which Architecture (32 Bit or 64 Bit Wine)
and then, on top of that You can install 32 or 64 Bit Python 2.7 or Python 3.7
by copying as explained before.

the whole process is a bit lengthy and there are many details You need to install, here the scripts (You need to download all of them and save them in the desired paths, because they depend on each other) :

```
#!/bin/bash
# ../home/install_wine.sh

function include_dependencies {
    local my_dir="$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )"  # this gives the full path, even for sourced scripts
    chmod +x "${my_dir}/lib_bash/*.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_color.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_retry.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_wine_install.sh"
}

include_dependencies  # me need to do that via a function to have local scope of my_dir




clr_bold clr_green "Install WINE"
check_wine_version

clr_green "add 386 Architecture"
retry sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
clr_green "add Wine Keys"
retry wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'
clr_green "Wine Packages Update"
retry sudo apt-get update
clr_green "Wine Packages Install"
retry sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-${wine_version}
retry sudo apt-get install -y cabextract
retry sudo apt-get install -y libxml2
retry sudo apt-get install -y libpng-dev

clr_green "Install latest Winetricks"
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/winetricks
retry sudo wget --directory-prefix=/usr/bin/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/winetricks
retry sudo winetricks -q --self-update
clr_green "Install latest Winetricks - done"

clr_green "done"
clr_green "******************************************************************************************************************"
clr_bold clr_green "FINISHED installing WINE and WINETRICKS"
clr_green "******************************************************************************************************************"
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# ../home/install_wine_machine.sh

function include_dependencies {
    local my_dir="$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )"  # this gives the full path, even for sourced scripts
    chmod +x "${my_dir}/lib_bash/*.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_color.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_retry.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_wine_install.sh"
}

include_dependencies  # me need to do that via a function to have local scope of my_dir

clr_bold clr_green "Install Wine Machine"
check_wine_prefix
check_wine_arch
check_wine_windows_version
check_headless_xvfb

clr_green "Setup Wine Machine at ${WINEPREFIX}, WINEARCH=${WINEARCH}, wine_windows_version=${wine_windows_version}"
mkdir -p ${WINEPREFIX}
wine_drive_c_dir=${WINEPREFIX}/drive_c
# xvfb-run --auto-servernum winecfg # fails marshal_object couldnt get IPSFactory buffer for interface ...

if [[ ${xvfb_framebuffer_service_active} == "True" ]]; then sudo service xvfb stop ; fi   # winecfg fails if xvfb server is running
winecfg
if [[ ${xvfb_framebuffer_service_active} == "True" ]]; then sudo service xvfb start ; fi     # winecfg fails if xvfb server is running

echo "Disable GUI Crash Dialogs"
winetricks nocrashdialog

echo "Set Windows Version to ${wine_windows_version}"
winetricks -q ${wine_windows_version}

echo "Install common Packets"

retry winetricks -q windowscodecs
retry winetricks -q msxml3

clr_green "done"
clr_green "******************************************************************************************************************"
clr_bold clr_green "FINISHED installing Wine Machine ${WINEPREFIX}"
clr_green "******************************************************************************************************************"
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# ../home/install_wine_python2_preinstalled.sh

function include_dependencies {
    local my_dir="$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )"  # this gives the full path, even for sourced scripts
    chmod +x "${my_dir}/lib_bash/*.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_color.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_retry.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_wine_install.sh"
}

include_dependencies  # me need to do that via a function to have local scope of my_dir

# if used outside github/travis You need to set :
# WINEARCH=win32    for 32 Bit Wine
# WINEARCH=         for 64 Bit Wine
# WINEPREFIX defaults to ${HOME}/.wine   or you need to pass it via environment variable
# if running headless, the xvfb service needs to run


clr_bold clr_green "Install Python 2.7 on WINE"
check_wine_prefix
check_wine_arch

wine_drive_c_dir=${WINEPREFIX}/drive_c
decompress_dir=${HOME}/bitranox_decompress
mkdir -p ${decompress_dir}

python_version_short=python27
python_version_doc="Python 2.7"

clr_green "Download ${python_version_doc} Binaries from https://github.com/bitranox/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine/archive/master.zip"
retry wget -nc --no-check-certificate -O ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master.zip https://github.com/bitranox/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine/archive/master.zip

clr_green "Unzip ${python_version_doc} Master to ${HOME}"
unzip -nqq ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master.zip -d ${decompress_dir}

if [[ "${WINEARCH}" == "win32" ]]
    then
        clr_green "Joining Multipart Zip in ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin"
        cat ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin/python*_wine_32* > ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin/joined_${python_version_short}.zip
        add_pythonpath="c:/Python27-32;c:/Python27-32/Scripts"
    else
        clr_green "Joining Multipart Zip in ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin"
        cat ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin/python*_wine_64* > ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin/joined_${python_version_short}.zip
        add_pythonpath="c:/Python27-64;c:/Python27-64/Scripts"
    fi

clr_green "Unzip ${python_version_doc} to ${wine_drive_c_dir}"
unzip -qq ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin/joined_${python_version_short}.zip -d ${wine_drive_c_dir}

prepend_path_to_wine_registry ${add_pythonpath}

clr_green "done"
clr_green "******************************************************************************************************************"
clr_bold clr_green "FINISHED installing Python 2.7 on Wine Machine ${WINEPREFIX}"
clr_green "******************************************************************************************************************"
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# ../home/install_wine_python3_preinstalled.sh

function include_dependencies {
    local my_dir="$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )"  # this gives the full path, even for sourced scripts
    chmod +x "${my_dir}/lib_bash/*.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_color.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_retry.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_wine_install.sh"
}

include_dependencies  # me need to do that via a function to have local scope of my_dir

# if used outside github/travis You need to set :
# WINEARCH=win32    for 32 Bit Wine
# WINEARCH=""       for 64 Bit Wine
# WINEPREFIX defaults to ${HOME}/.wine   or you need to pass it via environment variable

# if running headless, the xvfb service needs to run

clr_bold clr_green "Install Python 3.7 on WINE"
check_wine_prefix
check_wine_arch


wine_drive_c_dir=${WINEPREFIX}/drive_c
decompress_dir=${HOME}/bitranox_decompress
mkdir -p ${decompress_dir}

python_version_short=python37
python_version_doc="Python 3.7"

clr_green "Download ${python_version_doc} Binaries from https://github.com/bitranox/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine/archive/master.zip"
retry wget -nc --no-check-certificate -O ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master.zip https://github.com/bitranox/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine/archive/master.zip

clr_green "Unzip ${python_version_doc} Master to ${HOME}"
unzip -nqq ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master.zip -d ${decompress_dir}

if [[ "${WINEARCH}" == "win32" ]]
    then
        clr_green "Joining Multipart Zip in ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin"
        cat ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin/python*_wine_32* > ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin/joined_${python_version_short}.zip
        add_pythonpath="c:/Python37-32;c:/Python37-32/Scripts"
    else
        clr_green "Joining Multipart Zip in ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin"
        cat ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin/python*_wine_64* > ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin/joined_${python_version_short}.zip
        add_pythonpath="c:/Python37-64;c:/Python37-64/Scripts"
    fi

clr_green "Unzip ${python_version_doc} to ${wine_drive_c_dir}"
unzip -qq ${decompress_dir}/binaries_${python_version_short}_wine-master/bin/joined_${python_version_short}.zip -d ${wine_drive_c_dir}

prepend_path_to_wine_registry ${add_pythonpath}


clr_green "done"
clr_green "******************************************************************************************************************"
clr_bold clr_green "FINISHED installing Python 3.7 on Wine Machine ${WINEPREFIX}"
clr_green "******************************************************************************************************************"
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# ../home/install_wine_git_portable.sh

function include_dependencies {
    local my_dir="$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )"  # this gives the full path, even for sourced scripts
    chmod +x "${my_dir}/lib_bash/*.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_color.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_retry.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_bash/lib_wine_install.sh"
}

include_dependencies  # me need to do that via a function to have local scope of my_dir

# if used outside github/travis You need to set :
# WINEARCH=win32    for 32 Bit Wine
# WINEARCH=         for 64 Bit Wine
# WINEPREFIX defaults to ${HOME}/.wine   or you need to pass it via environment variable

# if running headless, the xvfb service needs to run

clr_bold clr_green "Install Git Portable"
check_wine_prefix
check_wine_arch

wine_drive_c_dir=${WINEPREFIX}/drive_c
decompress_dir=${HOME}/bitranox_decompress
mkdir -p ${decompress_dir}

clr_green "Download Git Portable Binaries"
retry wget -nc --no-check-certificate -O ${decompress_dir}/binaries_portable_git-master.zip https://github.com/bitranox/binaries_portable_git/archive/master.zip

clr_green "Unzip Git Portable Binaries Master to ${decompress_dir}"
unzip -nqq ${decompress_dir}/binaries_portable_git-master.zip -d ${decompress_dir}

if [[ "${WINEARCH}" == "win32" ]]
    then
        clr_green "Joining Multipart Zip in ${decompress_dir}/binaries_portable_git-master/bin"
        cat ${decompress_dir}/binaries_portable_git-master/bin/PortableGit32* > ${decompress_dir}/binaries_portable_git-master/bin/joined_PortableGit.zip
        add_git_path="c:/PortableGit32/cmd"
    else
        clr_green "Joining Multipart Zip in ${decompress_dir}/binaries_portable_git-master/bin"
        cat ${decompress_dir}/binaries_portable_git-master/bin/PortableGit64* > ${decompress_dir}/binaries_portable_git-master/bin/joined_PortableGit.zip
        add_git_path="c:/PortableGit64/cmd"
    fi

clr_green "Unzip Git Portable Binaries to ${wine_drive_c_dir}"
unzip -qq ${decompress_dir}/binaries_portable_git-master/bin/joined_PortableGit.zip -d ${wine_drive_c_dir}

prepend_path_to_wine_registry ${add_git_path}

clr_green "done"
clr_green "******************************************************************************************************************"
clr_bold clr_green "FINISHED installing Git Portable on Wine Machine ${WINEPREFIX}"
clr_green "******************************************************************************************************************"
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# ../home/lib_bash/lib_color.sh
#
# Constants and functions for terminal colors.
# Author: Max Tsepkov <max@yogi.pw>
# Manual see https://github.com/mercuriev/bash_colors
#


CLR_ESC="\033["

# All these variables has a function with the same name, but in lower case.
#
CLR_RESET=0             # reset all attributes to their defaults
CLR_RESET_UNDERLINE=24  # underline off
CLR_RESET_REVERSE=27    # reverse off
CLR_DEFAULT=39          # set underscore off, set default foreground color
CLR_DEFAULTB=49         # set default background color

CLR_BOLD=1              # set bold
CLR_BRIGHT=2            # set half-bright (simulated with color on a color display)
CLR_UNDERSCORE=4        # set underscore (simulated with color on a color display)
CLR_REVERSE=7           # set reverse video

CLR_BLACK=30            # set black foreground
CLR_RED=31              # set red foreground
CLR_GREEN=32            # set green foreground
CLR_BROWN=33            # set brown foreground
CLR_BLUE=34             # set blue foreground
CLR_MAGENTA=35          # set magenta foreground
CLR_CYAN=36             # set cyan foreground
CLR_WHITE=37            # set white foreground

CLR_BLACKB=40           # set black background
CLR_REDB=41             # set red background
CLR_GREENB=42           # set green background
CLR_BROWNB=43           # set brown background
CLR_BLUEB=44            # set blue background
CLR_MAGENTAB=45         # set magenta background
CLR_CYANB=46            # set cyan background
CLR_WHITEB=47           # set white background


# check if string exists as function
# usage: if fn_exists "sometext"; then ... fi
function fn_exists
{
    type -t "$1" | grep -q 'function'
}

# iterate through command arguments, o allow for iterative color application
function clr_layer
{
    # default echo setting
    CLR_ECHOSWITCHES="-e"
    CLR_STACK=""
    CLR_SWITCHES=""
    ARGS=("$@")

    # iterate over arguments in reverse
    for ((i=$#; i>=0; i--)); do
        ARG=${ARGS[$i]}
        # echo $ARG
        # set CLR_VAR as last argtype
        firstletter=${ARG:0:1}

        # check if argument is a switch
        if [ "$firstletter" = "-" ] ; then
            # if -n is passed, set switch for echo in clr_escape
            if [[ $ARG == *"n"* ]]; then
                CLR_ECHOSWITCHES="-en"
                CLR_SWITCHES=$ARG
            fi
        else
            # last arg is the incoming string
            if [ -z "$CLR_STACK" ]; then
                CLR_STACK=$ARG
            else
                # if the argument is function, apply it
                if [ -n "$ARG" ] && fn_exists $ARG; then
                    #continue to pass switches through recursion
                    CLR_STACK=$($ARG "$CLR_STACK" $CLR_SWITCHES)
                fi
            fi
        fi
    done

    # pass stack and color var to escape function
    clr_escape "$CLR_STACK" $1;
}

# General function to wrap string with escape sequence(s).
# Ex: clr_escape foobar $CLR_RED $CLR_BOLD
function clr_escape
{
    local result="$1"
    until [ -z "${2:-}" ]; do
    if ! [ $2 -ge 0 -a $2 -le 47 ] 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "clr_escape: argument \"$2\" is out of range" >&2 && return 1
    fi
        result="${CLR_ESC}${2}m${result}${CLR_ESC}${CLR_RESET}m"
    shift || break
    done

    echo "$CLR_ECHOSWITCHES" "$result"
}

function clr_reset           { clr_layer $CLR_RESET "$@";           }
function clr_reset_underline { clr_layer $CLR_RESET_UNDERLINE "$@"; }
function clr_reset_reverse   { clr_layer $CLR_RESET_REVERSE "$@";   }
function clr_default         { clr_layer $CLR_DEFAULT "$@";         }
function clr_defaultb        { clr_layer $CLR_DEFAULTB "$@";        }
function clr_bold            { clr_layer $CLR_BOLD "$@";            }
function clr_bright          { clr_layer $CLR_BRIGHT "$@";          }
function clr_underscore      { clr_layer $CLR_UNDERSCORE "$@";      }
function clr_reverse         { clr_layer $CLR_REVERSE "$@";         }
function clr_black           { clr_layer $CLR_BLACK "$@";           }
function clr_red             { clr_layer $CLR_RED "$@";             }
function clr_green           { clr_layer $CLR_GREEN "$@";           }
function clr_brown           { clr_layer $CLR_BROWN "$@";           }
function clr_blue            { clr_layer $CLR_BLUE "$@";            }
function clr_magenta         { clr_layer $CLR_MAGENTA "$@";         }
function clr_cyan            { clr_layer $CLR_CYAN "$@";            }
function clr_white           { clr_layer $CLR_WHITE "$@";           }
function clr_blackb          { clr_layer $CLR_BLACKB "$@";          }
function clr_redb            { clr_layer $CLR_REDB "$@";            }
function clr_greenb          { clr_layer $CLR_GREENB "$@";          }
function clr_brownb          { clr_layer $CLR_BROWNB "$@";          }
function clr_blueb           { clr_layer $CLR_BLUEB "$@";           }
function clr_magentab        { clr_layer $CLR_MAGENTAB "$@";        }
function clr_cyanb           { clr_layer $CLR_CYANB "$@";           }
function clr_whiteb          { clr_layer $CLR_WHITEB "$@";          }

# Outputs colors table
function clr_dump
{
    local T='gYw'

    echo -e "\n                 40m     41m     42m     43m     44m     45m     46m     47m";

    for FGs in '   0m' '   1m' '  30m' '1;30m' '  31m' '1;31m' \
               '  32m' '1;32m' '  33m' '1;33m' '  34m' '1;34m' \
               '  35m' '1;35m' '  36m' '1;36m' '  37m' '1;37m';
    do
        FG=${FGs// /}
        echo -en " $FGs \033[$FG  $T  "
        for BG in 40m 41m 42m 43m 44m 45m 46m 47m; do
            echo -en " \033[$FG\033[$BG  $T  \033[0m";
        done
        echo;
    done

    echo
    clr_bold "    Code     Function           Variable"
    echo \
'    0        clr_reset          $CLR_RESET
    1        clr_bold           $CLR_BOLD
    2        clr_bright         $CLR_BRIGHT
    4        clr_underscore     $CLR_UNDERSCORE
    7        clr_reverse        $CLR_REVERSE

    30       clr_black          $CLR_BLACK
    31       clr_red            $CLR_RED
    32       clr_green          $CLR_GREEN
    33       clr_brown          $CLR_BROWN
    34       clr_blue           $CLR_BLUE
    35       clr_magenta        $CLR_MAGENTA
    36       clr_cyan           $CLR_CYAN
    37       clr_white          $CLR_WHITE

    40       clr_blackb         $CLR_BLACKB
    41       clr_redb           $CLR_REDB
    42       clr_greenb         $CLR_GREENB
    43       clr_brownb         $CLR_BROWNB
    44       clr_blueb          $CLR_BLUEB
    45       clr_magentab       $CLR_MAGENTAB
    46       clr_cyanb          $CLR_CYANB
    47       clr_whiteb         $CLR_WHITEB
'
}

function fail {
  clr_bold clr_red "${1}" >&2
  exit 1
}

## make it possible to call functions without source include
# Check if the function exists (bash specific)
if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]
    then
        if declare -f "${1}" > /dev/null
        then
          # call arguments verbatim
          "$@"
        else
          # Show a helpful error
          function_name="${1}"
          library_name="${0}"
          fail "\"${function_name}\" is not a known function name of \"${library_name}\""
        fi
    fi
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# ../home/lib_bash/lib_retry.sh

function include_dependencies {
    local my_dir="$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )"  # this gives the full path, even for sourced scripts
    source "${my_dir}/lib_color.sh"
}

include_dependencies  # we need to do that via a function to have local scope of my_dir


function fail {
  clr_bold clr_red "${1}" >&2
  exit 1
}


function retry {
  local n=1
  local max=5
  local delay=5
  while true; do
    my_command="${@}"
    "$@" && break || {
      if [[ $n -lt $max ]]; then
        ((n++))
        clr_bold clr_red "Command \"${my_command}\" failed. Attempt ${n}/${max}:"
        sleep $delay;
      else
        fail "The command \"${my_command}\" has failed after ${n} attempts."
      fi
    }
  done
}


## make it possible to call functions without source include
# Check if the function exists (bash specific)
if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]
    then
        if declare -f "${1}" > /dev/null
        then
          # call arguments verbatim
          "$@"
        else
          # Show a helpful error
          function_name="${1}"
          library_name="${0}"
          fail "\"${function_name}\" is not a known function name of \"${library_name}\""
        fi
    fi
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# ../home/lib_bash/lib_wine_install.sh

function include_dependencies {
    local my_dir="$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )"  # this gives the full path, even for sourced scripts
    chmod +x "${my_dir}/*.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_color.sh"
    source "${my_dir}/lib_retry.sh"
}

include_dependencies  # we need to do that via a function to have local scope of my_dir


function fail {
  clr_bold clr_red "${1}" >&2
  exit 1
}


function check_wine_version {
    if [[ -z ${wine_version} ]]
        then
            clr_bold clr_red "WARNING - no wine_version in environment set - set now to default: devel"
            echo "available Versions: stable, devel, staging"
            export wine_version="devel"
        fi
}


function check_wine_prefix {
    ## set wine prefix to ${HOME}/.wine if not given by environment variable
    if [[ -z ${WINEPREFIX} ]]
        then
            clr_bold clr_red "WARNING - no WINEPREFIX in environment - set now to ${HOME}/.wine"
            export WINEPREFIX=${HOME}/.wine
        fi
}

function check_wine_arch {
    if [[ -z ${WINEARCH} ]]
        then
            clr_bold clr_red "WARNING - no WINEARCH in environment - will install 64 Bit Wine"
            clr_bold clr_red "in Order to install 32Bit You need to set WINEARCH=\"win32\""
            clr_bold clr_red "in Order to install 64Bit You need to set WINEARCH=\"\""
        fi
}


function check_wine_windows_version {
    if [[ -z ${wine_windows_version} ]]
        then
            clr_bold clr_red "WARNING - no wine_windows_version in environment - set now to win10"
            clr_bold clr_red "available Versions: win10, win2k, win2k3, win2k8, win31, win7, win8, win81, win95, win98, winxp"
            export wine_windows_version="win10"
        fi
}


function check_headless_xvfb {
    clr_green "Check if we run headless and xvfb Server is running"
    export xvfb_framebuffer_service_active="False"
    systemctl is-active --quiet xvfb && export xvfb_framebuffer_service_active="True"
    # run winetricks with xvfb if needed
    if [[ ${xvfb_framebuffer_service_active} == "True" ]]
        then
            clr_green "we run headless, xvfb service is running"
        else
            clr_green "we run on normal console, xvfb service is not running"
        fi
}

function prepend_path_to_wine_registry {
    add_pythonpath="${1}"
    clr_green "add Path Settings to Registry"
    wine_current_reg_path="`wine reg QUERY \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\" /v PATH | grep REG_SZ | sed 's/^.*REG_SZ\s*//'`"
    wine_new_reg_path="${add_pythonpath};${wine_current_reg_path}"
    wine reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /t REG_SZ /v PATH /d "${wine_new_reg_path}" /f
    wine_actual_reg_path="`wine reg QUERY \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\" /v PATH | grep REG_SZ | sed 's/^.*REG_SZ\s*//'`"
    clr_green "adding Path done"
    clr_bold clr_green "Wine Registry PATH=${wine_actual_reg_path}"
}


## make it possible to call functions without source include
# Check if the function exists (bash specific)
if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]
    then
        if declare -f "${1}" > /dev/null
        then
          # call arguments verbatim
          "$@"
        else
          # Show a helpful error
          function_name="${1}"
          library_name="${0}"
          fail "\"${function_name}\" is not a known function name of \"${library_name}\""
        fi
    fi
```